# Why Tkinter create_image becomes fast after asksaveasfilename runed?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.8

I'm making a simple image viewer for study Tkinter.
The code is below.
I noticed that `disp_img()` becomes fast after `asksaveasfilename()` runed.
Default `disp_img()` process time is about 0.04s.
The disp_img() after `asksaveasfilename()` is about 0.002s.
I checked detail about `disp_img()`'s process by cProfile.
I noticed `create_image()` becomes fast.

Why tkinter's `create_image()` become fast after `saveasfilename()` runed ?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import numpy as np
import time
import cProfile as profile
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageOps

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()

        self.master.title("Image Viewer") 
        self.master.geometry("400x300")

        #filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(
        #  title = "Save As",
        #  filetypes = [("Image file", ".bmp .png .jpg .tif"), 
        #               ("Bitmap", ".bmp"), ("PNG", ".png"), 
        #               ("JPEG", ".jpg"), ("Tiff", ".tif") ],
        #  initialdir = "./"
        #  )
        
        self.back_color = "#008B8B"
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master, bg = self.back_color)
        self.canvas.pack(expand = True, fill = tk.BOTH)
    
        self.update_idletasks()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
    
        self.pil_img = None
        self.after(10, self.timeEvent)
    
    def disp_image(self):
        disp_start_time = time.time()
    
        img_array = np.zeros((240,320,3), np.uint8)
        self.pil_img = Image.fromarray(img_array)
        self.photo_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.pil_img)
    
        self.canvas.create_image(
            self.canvas_width / 2,
            self.canvas_height / 2,
            image=self.photo_img
            )
    
        print("disp time = "+str(time.time() - disp_start_time))
    
    def timeEvent(self):
        profile.runctx('self.disp_image()', globals(), locals())
        print('')
        self.after(10, self.timeEvent)
    
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(master = root)
    app.mainloop()
```

When the code is uncommented, the code becomes fast.

Part of the cProfile results is below.

- Default

> disp time 0.04877352714538574
> 84 function calls in 0.049 seconds
>
> Ordered by: standard name
>
> ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.049    0.049 :1()
> 3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:2644(_check_size)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:2662(new)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:2701(frombytes)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:2739(frombuffer)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:2792(fromarray)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:413(_getdecoder)
> 2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:524(**init**)
> 3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:556(size)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:560(_new)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:788(frombytes)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:814(load)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ImageTk.py:117(**del**)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ImageTk.py:125(**str**)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ImageTk.py:151(paste)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ImageTk.py:85(**init**)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 **init**.py:101(_cnfmerge)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 **init**.py:1468(_options)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.048    0.048 **init**.py:2768(_create)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.048    0.048 **init**.py:2788(create_image)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 **init**.py:291(_get_default_root)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 **init**.py:3994(**init**)
> 2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 **init**.py:4012(**str**)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 **init**.py:4014(**del**)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 **init**.py:4059(**init**)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.049    0.049 igl_display_py.py:33(disp_image)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method PIL._imaging.fill}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method PIL._imaging.raw_decoder}
> 2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method _tkinter._flatten}
> 3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.callable}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.049    0.049 {built-in method builtins.exec}
> 2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.getattr}
> 2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.hasattr}
> 11    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
> 7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.print}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method numpy.zeros}
> 2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method time.time}
> 4    0.048    0.012    0.048    0.012 {method 'call' of '_tkinter.tkapp' objects}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'convert2' of 'ImagingCore' objects}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'copy' of 'dict' objects}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'decode' of 'ImagingDecoder' objects}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'getint' of '_tkinter.tkapp' objects}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'isblock' of 'ImagingCore' objects}
> 2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'items' of 'dict' objects}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'new_block' of 'ImagingCore' objects}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'pixel_access' of 'ImagingCore' objects}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'setimage' of 'ImagingDecoder' objects}
> 2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'update' of 'dict' objects}

- Uncommented

> disp time = 0.0014710426330566406
> 84 function calls in 0.002 seconds
>
> Ordered by: standard name
>
> ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 :1()
> 3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:2644(_check_size)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:2662(new)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:2701(frombytes)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:2739(frombuffer)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:2792(fromarray)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:413(_getdecoder)
> 2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:524(**init**)
> 3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:556(size)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:560(_new)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:788(frombytes)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:814(load)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ImageTk.py:117(**del**)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ImageTk.py:125(**str**)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ImageTk.py:151(paste)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ImageTk.py:85(**init**)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 **init**.py:101(_cnfmerge)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 **init**.py:1468(_options)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 **init**.py:2768(_create)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 **init**.py:2788(create_image)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 **init**.py:291(_get_default_root)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 **init**.py:3994(**init**)
> 2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 **init**.py:4012(**str**)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 **init**.py:4014(**del**)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 **init**.py:4059(**init**)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 igl_display_py.py:33(disp_image)
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method PIL._imaging.fill}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method PIL._imaging.raw_decoder}
> 2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method _tkinter._flatten}
> 3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.callable}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.002 {built-in method builtins.exec}
> 2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.getattr}
> 2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.hasattr}
> 11    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
> 7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.print}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method numpy.zeros}
> 2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method time.time}
> 4    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'call' of '_tkinter.tkapp' objects}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'convert2' of 'ImagingCore' objects}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'copy' of 'dict' objects}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'decode' of 'ImagingDecoder' objects}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'getint' of '_tkinter.tkapp' objects}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'isblock' of 'ImagingCore' objects}
> 2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'items' of 'dict' objects}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'new_block' of 'ImagingCore' objects}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'pixel_access' of 'ImagingCore' objects}
> 1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'setimage' of 'ImagingDecoder' objects}
> 2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'update' of 'dict' objects}

Comment: Try changing `self.after(10, self.timeEvent)` to `self.after(200, self.timeEvent)`. I think that `asksaveasfilename` runs an event loop that helps set up the `tk.Tk`.

Comment: I tried to change ```self.after()``` in ```__init__()``` to ```self.after(200, self.timeEvent)``` but the default process time didn't change. I also tried to change ```timeEvent()``` 's one and the default process time in ```disp_image()``` becomes about 0.02s. It is 1/10 speed than the uncommented code.